# About the sentence : She is circling a pen on a paper

Tags: sentence-meaning

I wrote this sentence:

> She is circling a pen on a paper.

I intend to mean:

> She is spinning a pen on a paper.

But using the dictionary, I can't find any definition that the verb 'circle' has a meaning of 'cause something to circle' in transitive form.

Can the verb in that sentence mean "to cause something to circle"?

Comment: Since you could not find such definition in a dictionary, you must be right. You may have noticed that those definitions refer to something going around something else. "spinning" (rotating) has a different meaning. In the same way, while you can "spin" a top on a piece of paper, you can't say you "circled" it.

Comment: The only sense I can make out of "She is circling a pen on a paper." is that she is walking around a pen that is on a piece of paper.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence

> She is circling a pen on a paper.

sounds like it is describing a pen lying on a piece of paper and someone drawing a circle around the pen. Something like this where the pen would be in the center of the circles:

[image]

Which may also be called **doodling**.

If you say

> The pen is *spinning* on the paper

it means the pen itself is spinning on an axis while lying on the paper and does not necessarily mean any marks are being made on the paper.

> circling

is the act of something going around something else, usually the cause for something to circle is given in a greater context.

Comment: 'He circled his arms around his wife's waist.' This example I found is on Merriam Webster Dictionary. So, Is it possible that meaning has 'To cause something to circle' in particular context?

Comment: You do not know the *cause* of the circling, only that his arms were around her waist. Maybe he just wanted to give her a hug, maybe she was falling and he wanted to stop her...  It's similar to "He drove to the next city.", you don't know why he drove there.

Comment: According to your explanation, how do you express the circle meaning on MWD example?

Comment: However, I think in any situation on the example the cause should be his will.

Comment: Because his arm can't move itself, unless he move it by his will, so that the cause in your comment explanation is just his will to move his arm.

Answer (score 0):

As @user3169 mentioned, you would likely be better off using a verb such as "to spin", instead. You can also use the verb "twirl" or "whirl".

I found these similar definitions using a quick google search:

"To spin":

> Cause to turn or whirl around quickly

"To twirl":

> Cause to rotate

"To whirl":

> Move or cause to move rapidly around and around

As you mentioned, I was unable to find a similar definition for "to circle".

Comment: But how about this 'He circled his arms around his wife's waist.' This example I found is on Merriam Webster Dictionary. So, Is it possible that meaning has 'To cause something to circle' in particular context?

Comment: @SIS You didn't use "around" in your example. But if you were to say "She is circling a pen around a paper." might be grammatically OK, but logically she would need magic to make the pen go around the paper.

Comment: @user3169 why do you think the situation a magic? I don't agree to your thinking. Because I think she keeps holding a pen in her hand and the pen is circling on. Why is it a magic? Please,  could you account for me about this?

Comment: If I used the preposition 'around' , however, I don't think it is a magic. She is holding a pen in her hand and keep circling with the pen. But I partly agree to your thinking, despite before my thought, in that your thought can be a part in the situations the around-added sentence has.

Comment: "She is circling a pen..." is saying that she is moving the pen. I suppose she could be holding the pen and moving herself, but a more literal interpretation would be that she is making the pen move by itself (that would involve magic).

Comment: @user3169 "She is circling a pen." is an ambiguous sentence I think and could be interpreted in two as 'she is circling around a pen' or 'she is drawing circles with a pen' if 'around' were not in.  So, if we want to descirbe the latter situation, must add preposition 'around'. Do you agree with my thinking?

Comment: But still, what is going around what?